# Unexpected characters in formatting day

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Trying to follow https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates#common_pitfalls I have the following

```
var format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'

var MILLIS_PER_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60;
var now = new Date();
var oneHourago = new Date(now.getTime() - MILLIS_PER_HOUR);


var oneHouragoFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(oneHourago, "EST", format);
Logger.log(oneHouragoFormatted);

return
```

The output :

```
[18-12-21 11:34:27:377 EST] 2018-12-355 10:12
```

Why does it have 355?

Comment: Because that is the day (of the year) and not the date (in the current month).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that is the day (of the year) and not the date (in the current month).

You need to use a lower-case 'd'.

```
var format = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'
```

The documentation will eventually point you to the [java.text.SimpleDateFormat.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)